# printf specifier does not work as expected

Tags: c, printf

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

printf("%2s\n","Monday"); //output: Monday
getch();
}
```

Above code prints whole Monday. I want it to print "Mo". Why doesn't this work in Visual Studio or am I coding wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace `"%2s"` by `"%.2s"`.

```
printf("%.2s\n","Monday");
```

Answer (score 6):

`%2s` specifies the padding, which will never shorten the string. To print fewer characters than are present in the string, specify the precision as `%.2s`:

```
printf("%.2s", "Monday"); //output: Mo
```

Also, note that `getch` is not a standard C function.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
printf("%.2s\n","Monday");
```

More info for these http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/printf-format-strings.html